# Force if statement to execute only once

Tags: c

I have a piece of code that will be executed many times (5,000+), and an if statement that will be true only the first time. I've thought of using a "FIRST" variable and compare it each time, but it just seems like a waste to check it every single time, even if I know it's not needed.

```
bool FIRST = true;

void foo(){
if(FIRST){
   /* do something only once */
   FIRST = false;
}
   /* something something... */
}
```

I also don't know if there is some compiler optimization that does this automatically, or another way to do it; if there is, please let me know.

And yes, I know that a mere if statement isn't a big thing, but it just annoys me.

Comment: Maybe you can refactor the code so the first case is not in the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the function via a function pointer and remove the `if` check on the second call by changing the function pointer to a function without the `if`:

```
void foo_init(void);
void foo_real(void);    
void (*foo)(void) = foo_init;

void foo_init(void) {
   foo = foo_real;
   /* do something only once */
   foo_real();
}

void foo_real(void) {
   /* something something... */
}

int main() { 
    foo();
    foo();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the test? The function only gets called when `foo == foo_init`

Comment: Och right, so it could be just removed. I think I was thinking to make the function thread-safe - then a mutex in the function body + check `if (foo == foo_init)` is needed.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using gcc, there are macros called `unlikely` and `likely` that can allow it to make optimizations based on a condition.

In your case the condition will only be true the first time, so you would use `unlikely`:

```
if (unlikely(FIRST)) {
```

Comment: in this case we still need set FIRST to the false? Can't get it how this works ...

Comment: @NickS The rest of the code doesn't change.  All this does is tell the compiler the condition will be false most of the time and to optimize for that case.

Answer (score 4):

From a compiler optimization point of view, I think an `if` statement is your best bet, as it will probably compile down to something like a single [`JNZ`](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html), so as long as `FIRST` stays true, it will be pretty optimized.

You might also want to take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841169/jnz-cmp-assembly-instructions)

Answer (score 3):

Make `foo` and `fooFirst`, and then call like this

```
fooFirst();
for (...) {
   foo();
}
```

`foo` and `fooFirst` can share code.